# How can I sign an assembly that reference unsigned COM interop assemblies?

Tags: .net, com, interop, strongname

When I try to sign the assembly I get the following error:

> Error  1   Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'comlib' does not have a strong name

Is it possible to sign an assembly that reference unsigned assemblies or do I have to sign the COM interop assemblies as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will have to sign everything.

For a good explanation as to *why* you would need to do this, I would recommend that you read Eric Lippert's [Alas, Smith and Jones](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/04/alas-smith-and-jones.aspx):

> If assembly Smith is a strong-named
>   assembly, and Smith says that assembly
>   Jones is its friend, then Jones must
>   also be strong-named. If, however,
>   Smith is not strong-named, then Jones
>   need not be strong-named either.
>
> I'm occasionally asked "what's up with
>   that?"

**Edit:** *He doesn't mention COM, but the theory still applies to your situation.*

Comment: Indeed. The situation I am talking about in the blog is not exactly this situation -- there I am talking about "friend assemblies" -- but the _logic_ of why this is illegal is exactly the same in both cases.